# input string look up of a list and return that value and the correlating index of another list

Tags: python

```
# Welcome Message
print("Welcome to the Country and Capital look up program. If you enter a country found on our list"
      "\nit will display the capital to you. If you enter a Country that's not on the list it'll prompt"
      "\nyou to try another search.\n")

# Defining the function main. Not sure what to put under it so I have a blank print statement
def main():
    print()

# My assignment is to create 2 separate blank lists from the text file that has country,capital
countryList = []
capitalList = []

# The with open allows for the file to be auto closed once no longer being called
# Per the assignment I'm using the split command to remove the comma separating the country and capital
with open (r'D:\Python\Countries_capitals_20Rows.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        country, capital = line.replace("\n","").split(",")
        countryList.append(country)
        capitalList.append(capital)

# The most non-pythonic way of making this program work since I couldn't get it to work by taking a input string and searching in the countryList and then finding the matching value or same index reference in the capitalList
while True:
    answer = (str(input("\nEnter a Country name to find it's Capital: "))) # ask user for the name of a country
    if answer == 'Afghanistan':
        print("The capital of Afghanistan is Kabul")
        break
    elif answer == 'Bahamas':
        print("The capital of Bahamas is Nassau")
        break
    elif answer == 'Cuba':
        print("The capital of Cuba is Havana")
        break
    elif answer == 'Denmark':
        print("The capital of Denmark is Copenhagen")
        break
    elif answer == 'Egypt':
        print("The capital of Egypt is Cairo")
        break
    elif answer == 'France':
        print("The capital of France is Paris")
        break
    elif answer == 'Germany':
        print("The capital of Germany is Berlin")
        break
    elif answer == 'Hungary':
        print("The capital of Hungary is Budapest")
        break
    elif answer == 'India':
        print("The capital of India is New Delhi")
        break
    elif answer == 'Japan':
        print("The capital of Japan is Tokyo")
        break
    elif answer == 'Kenya':
        print("The capital of Kenya is Nairobi")
        break
    elif answer == 'Mexico':
        print("The capital of Mexico is Mexico City")
        break
    elif answer == 'Norway':
        print("The capital of Norway is Oslo")
        break
    elif answer == 'Puerto Rico':
        print("The capital of Puerto Rico is San Juan")
        break
    elif answer == 'Qatar':
        print("The capital of Qatar is Doha")
        break
    elif answer == 'Russia':
        print("The capital of Russia is Moscow")
        break
    elif answer == 'South Korea':
        print("The capital of South Korea is Seoul")
        break
    elif answer == 'Thailand':
        print("The capital of Thailand is Bangkok")
        break
    elif answer == 'United States':
        print("The capital of United States is Washington DC")
        break
    elif answer == 'Venezuela':
        print("The capital of Venezuela is Caracas")
        break
    elif answer == 'Zimbabwe':
        print("The capital of Zimbabwe is Harare")
        break

# My notes regarding the method I tried to get working that did not work
"""
Beginning of Loop
I first had a print("Found it") until I could figure how to print the country from countryList and capital from
capitalList. For some reason when I enter print(country,capital) it prints the last entry in the countryList and
capitalList. I also created a for country, capital in sorted(zip) that displays them both side by side, but can't
figure how to search for a user input in a list and index it so that it knows how to pull the same index number from
the other list. I reviewed so much code online for over 7 hours this week and found no one doing that. I searched
my class notes for the list n lists and didn't see how to make it work based on a user input, only entering the index
number manually. So I'm commenting out my code below and going to write a if, elif for each option

while True:
    answer = (str(input("\nEnter a Country name to find it's Capital: "))) # ask user for the name of a country
    if answer in countryList:
        print(country, capital)
        break
    print("\nSorry, the Country you entered is not in my database. Please try enter another Country from the list below:\n")
    print(countryList)
    print(capitalList)
    for country, capital in sorted(zip(countryList, capitalList)):
        print(country, capital)
"""

# Allows for the function to be defined above or below the call statement
if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

Comment: I'm new to python and sorry if that wasn't the proper way of posting what I'm having a problem with. I'm still trying to understand some of the basic principles such as storing input from a user into either a  list, tuple or dictionary in which I can call it and various other entries in other lists, tuples or dictionaries to display the results to the user. I can't ever seem to find a good place to look a full code to understand this. Thanks in advance for anyone that can help. I'd greatly appreciate a rewrite of the program top down so I can see how I should be programming this correctly. Thx

Comment: First, welcome to StackOverflow.  Second, please format your code correctly.  See [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for guidelines.  Third, you need to formulate your question clearly, and only post the code you need to establish a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  <-- Please use these guidelines to rewrite your post.

Comment: @cyberjax21 , try to minimise your code as much as possible. Give only the relevant parts and explain what you have done and what you want separately, not in the code itself! And finally provide the `input` and the `expected output`.